# insert multiple checkbox values php ajax

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, foreach

Please help me, This matter ruined my days . I tried with ajax and php, post these codes in previous thread, but can't get answer or any guide. I think my question or code are unclear. So here I Post what I actually need. Please help me or provide any links that helps.

HTML. It is dynamic and would be generated from php

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="News">News
    <ul>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][]" value="politics">Politics
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu[][]" value="Social">Social
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="Views">Views                                 
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="Art">Art                               
</li>

<form>
</form>
```

While inserting multiple values it should be inserted as follow. If each menu has subcategory, then each checked value would be inserted in `subcat_id`, if has not then `Null` value.

[image]

What I tried :

Ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var navid = [];
        $("input[name='menu[]']:checked").each(function(){
            navid.push(this.value);
        });
    var subnavid = [];
        $("input[name='menu[][]']:checked").each(function(){
            subnavid.push(this.value);
        });
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append('navid', navid);
        formData.append('subnavid', subnavid);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'upload.php',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
      });
```

PHP

```
$data = explode("," ,$_POST["navid"]); 
subdata = explode("," ,$_POST["subnavid"]);
foreach ($data AS $key => $menu){
   foreach($subdata AS $k => $submenu){
   ......
   ......
   }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest logging the entire contents of `POST` (printing `print_r($_POST, true)` to a file would work) in your PHP file and watching what's in it each time you check or uncheck one of your checkboxes.  That will tell you (1) if your AJAX is firing correctly and (2) what the data structure coming to your PHP is so you can extract the data correctly.

Comment: `name="menu[][]"` doesn't make sense here. For every item on the sublevel you add a distict item on the top level (containing an array with only one element). You should put a special index in the first bracket, such as `name='menu["subitems"][]'`

Comment: @Psi, thanks, how can I pass array with nested array through ajax ? Main problem is here- my above ajax code considers only one's nested array as common nested array of other.